# The limit of the function $(1-x^2)/\sin(\pi x)$ as $x\to 1$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

What is $${\lim_{x \to 1}} \frac{1-x^2}{\sin(\pi x)} \text{ ?} $$ I got it as $0$ but answer in the book as $2/ \pi$. Can you guys tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Note i dont want l hospital

Comment: Then probably (after some rework), you have to somehow use that $\frac{sin(t)}{t} $ goes to $1$ as $t$ goes to $0$.

Comment: If you show how $0$ appeared in your attempt, then others may help where error occurred.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar  If you want to avoid L'Hospital rule, you should mention that explicitly in your post - not just in a comment - and add ([tag:limits-without-lhopital]) tag.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x-1=t$, then
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1-x^2}{\sin \pi x} &= \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{-t(t+2)}{\sin (\pi(t+1))}\\
&=\lim_{t\to 0} \left(\frac{t}{\sin \pi t}\cdot (t+2)\right)\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}
\end{align}

Comment: Should be $-t(t+2)$

Comment: @Bubububu Thanks, but I edited it just now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that using the L'Hospital rule we trivially get the answer in the book.
Differentiating the numerator and denominator we get:

$$\frac{-2x}{\cos(\pi x) \cdot \pi} $$

Since the above function is continuous at $x=1$, the limit is:

$$\frac{-2.1}{\cos(\pi \cdot 1) \cdot \pi} $$

$$\frac{-2\cdot1}{-1 \cdot \pi} = \frac{2}{\pi}$$

Comment: L'Hopital is very efficient and often succeeds where cruder methods fail, but also often gives no insight. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

You have 
 $${1-x^2 \over \sin(\pi x)}= {(1-x)(1+x)\over \sin(\pi x)}\sim {2(1-x)\over \sin(\pi x)}. $$

Now look at the definition of the derivative for $\sin$ at $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& \lim_{x\to1} \frac{(1-x)(1+x)}{\sin(\pi x)} = \lim_{x\to1} \frac{(1+x)(1-x)}{\sin(\pi(1-x))} \\[10pt]
= {} & \underbrace{\left( \lim_{x\to1} (1+x) \right)  \left( \frac 1 \pi \lim_{x\to1} \frac{\pi(1-x)}{\sin(\pi(1-x)} \right)}_{\text{(See the remark on this below.)}} = 2 \cdot \frac 1 \pi \lim_{u\to 0} \frac u {\sin u}
\end{align}
where $u=\pi(1-x)$.  That the last limit is $1$ is something you would be presumed to have seen before.

Breaking it into two limits like that is permissible if both limits exist and are finite numbers, and in this case we see that they are.