# Where is the mistake in this solution of $\lim_{x \to 1}{\frac{1-x^2}{\sin (\pi x)}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to solve this limit:

> $$\lim_{x \to 1}{\frac{1-x^2}{\sin (\pi x)}}$$

The answer ought to be $\frac{2}{\pi}$, but I end up with $0$:

$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}{\frac{1-x^2}{\sin (\pi x)}} = $
$\lim\limits_{y \to 0}{\frac{1-(y+1)^2}{\sin (\pi (y+1))}} = $
$\lim\limits_{y \to 0}{\frac{\pi(y+1)}{\sin (\pi (y+1))} \frac{1-(y+1)^2}{\pi(y+1)}} = $
$\lim\limits_{y \to 0}{\frac{1-(y+1)^2}{\pi(y+1)}} =  0$

**Where and why is my solution incorrect?**

---

**Note:** I'm aware of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700347/the-limit-of-the-function-1-x2-sin-pi-x-as-x-to-1), however I believe mine is different because I'm asking *where and why my solution* went wrong, not *why my answer* was wrong.

Comment: The step where you have $\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{\pi (y+1)}{\sin(\pi(y+1)}$ and say that limit is equal to $1,$ how did you get that ?

Comment: I don't see how you can drop the π(y+1) / sin(π(y+1)) in the final step.  sin(pi) goes to zero which you may not divide by, so you need to use L'Hôpital's method from the get-go.

Comment: First write $\sin(\pi(y+1))=-\sin\pi y$ then add in numerator and denominator .

Comment: @MyGlasses -- Will try. Thanks!

Comment: @MyGlasses That is slick! I will have to remember that little nugget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third equality attempts to make use of the rule $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\sin x} = 1$, but note that yours has $y\to 0$ yet the *argument* is not $y$, it is $\pi(y+1)$, which does *not* go to zero. That's where your work goes wrong.

Comment: Oh! I see. I'll see how I can fix it, and come back later if more help is needed. Thanks in the meantime!

Comment: @SirJony You are welcome. Your idea is very clever, even though it didn't work. MyGlasses seems to have a good workaround idea in the comments above, though if it were me, I would just use L'Hospital's rule, if that is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim _{ y\to 0 }{ \frac { \pi (y+1) }{ \sin  (\pi (y+1)) }  } =\frac { \pi  }{ 0 } \neq 1\\ $$

Comment: How come? I thought $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\frac{\sin x}{x}} = 1$ (which is the identity I used).

Comment: @SirJony see my answer. Your identity is correct, but the *argument* of the sine function needs to go to zero, which yours does not.